# Adaptar código CSS para div de ancho responsive

Tags: css, div, responsive, scss

He declarado una class llamada #inner en CSS para aplicar a un determinado div que posee la propiedad `width: 50%;` pero quisiera que al visualizarlo en un dispositivo móvil la propiedad width fuese del 100% `width: 100%;`

He pensado en hacerlo de la siguiente forma, pero lo he probado en mi smartphone y no funciona:

```
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #inner{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacer que funcione?

Comment: Hola pedro,si hablas de definir una `clase` recuerda que estas en `CSS` se toman con `.`(punto) el `#` es para los `id`. y si quieres un sitio `responsive` te recomiendo usar `BOOTSTRAP` es sencillo y mucho mejor

Comment: @Pedro ya solucionaste tu problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asegurate que en tu `HTML` cuentes con el `meta-viewport`, y un consejo al momento de alterar el width al 100%, con el padding que le estas dando el div generara scroll horizontal por lo cual con `calc` al 100% de la pagina le restaras `80px` que seria la suma de los `40px` a cada lado del `div` que le das con el `padding`.

```css
#inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 50%;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    }



@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #inner {
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<div id="inner"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que hiciste no está mal pero es posible que la resolución de tu smartphone sea más grande que la que declaraste en el media query, por ende no se aplica el `width: 100%`.
La mejor opción es hacer, lo que se denomina como, **mobile first** que quiere decir que primero se maqueta en *mobile* y después se agrega los media query para *tablet* y por último *desktop*.

```
#inner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #inner{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    #inner{
        width: 33%;
    }
}
```

Otra cosa que deberías saber es que las clases son atributos `class` y se llaman desde el **css** con un "punto", por ejemplo `.inner {}` y los id con el hashtag.